# Single word for "being too much like a student"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, suffixes

To clarify, being too much like a student can mean one of the following:

- insistent on being "right" rather than flexible/diplomatic
- (at workplace) passively waiting to be assigned "homework" rather than actively participate
- (at workplace) overestimating what they can do with the knowledge gained at school
- being too much of an idealist/perfectionist
- ....

Roughly speaking, anything that's related to the *naive* aspects of being a student can fall under this list. I know it might sound a bit vague, but you can think of it just like "childish" as to "child" and "girlish" as to "girl". However, as far as I searched there is no such word as "student-ish", so does there exist a word that means "student-ish"?

Comment: Student-like, or the same without the hyphen

Comment: @Clare thanks. This is acceptable but I just wonder if there's a more single-word (or less artificial) option.

Comment: studious is the adjective from student, but it does not convey the negative aspects you are listing; and 'unstudious' only conveys a lack of studying.

Comment: In Indian English, "fresher" might do it.

Comment: *[Sophomoric](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sophomoric)* covers a lot of that.

Comment: @PhilSweet wow this is excellently suited to the third one!

Comment: Perhaps *Bookish*?

Comment: I think that whole concept is offensive to students and I would try to deal with the individual concepts individually as applicable.

Comment: @Jim that's alright. Thanks. (in my language there exists a word like "student-ish" which corresponds exactly to these traits. And I wouldn't take it as offensive just as I wouldn't take "childish" as an offensive concept to children.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sophomoric**

[1 :conceited and overconfident of knowledge but poorly informed and immature a sophomoric argument
2 :lacking in maturity, taste, or judgment sophomoric humor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sophomoric)

However, a single word may not describe all the bulleted traits. Each is likely a different word.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word itself conveys the well known negative aspects of student behaviour.

In the same vein, one might say, 'You are behaving like a teenager !' This sentence could, in fact, be addressed to a teenager, implying that the person was not progressing through their teenage years towards adulthood.

It is in accord with the parallel which the OP states regarding 'child' and 'childish'. Some words convey within them the characteristics - and they may be negative ones - of that which they describe.

So a 'student' is someone whom we expect to behave in a certain way. If they do not, we may refer to them as 'a good student' or 'an exceptional student' but, for the time being, they remain 'a student' with all that that implies.

The OP states, 'too much like a student' and that underlines the fact that we all *know* how students tend to behave.

We neither need, nor have, another word to describe the *adverse* side of student behaviour because so many students, well, behave like students.

Answer (score 0):

[Novice](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/novice)

> a person who is new to the circumstances, work, etc., in which he or she is placed; beginner; tyro